# Select the number of unique rows based on a certain criterium

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique

I'm trying to find unique names per region. I have a (long) list of names and regions and I want to know which names occur in just one region.

How can I do this efficiently?

The data looks like this:

```
name - region - ... 
Merlangius merlangus - North Atlantic - ... 
Gadus morhua - North Atlantic - ... 
Limanda limanda - North Atlantic - ... 
Merlangius merlangus - North Atlantic - ... 
Limanda limanda - South Atlantic - ...
```

The output should give me the names and regions of species that only occur in that one region. In this case it should result in something like this:

```
name - region - ... 
Merlangius merlangus - North Atlantic - ... 
Gadus morhua - North Atlantic - ...
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Post the tables structure and some sample data. After you do that, show us what is the expected output. But don't stop at that, show us what you have tried (queries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause.</strike>

In fact you can do this

```
create table test(name varchar(10),region varchar(10));

insert into test values('Joe','US');
insert into test values('Bill','US');
insert into test values('Joe','UK');
insert into test values('Stu','US');
insert into test values('Stu','UK');

Select name from test where name not in (
Select name
From (
select name,row_number() over(partition by region order by name) as rn
from test
)z
where z.rn>1
 )
```

**Output**

Bill

And here is the [**SQL Fiddle DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/95f2f/8)

Comment: An answer as completely minimal as the question. Fair enough, really.